# Group Policy Objects (GPOs) for Linux

Tags: networking, dual-boot, mount

I have a windows server and different platform clients. I want to set up group/domain policy on my network.

Is there any solution to implement GPO for Ubuntu client substitute of third party software?

How can I enable pop up message notifies Ubuntu users to change his/her password before password expiration date?

Best regards...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the approach to managing GPOs on Ubuntu using the example of the French gendarmerie.

https://github.com/skosachiov/remediations-gendbuntu

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).